# How to create a RDF file by some triple data？

Tags: python, sparql, rdf, knowledge-graph

I means if I have many triple data, like "h1 r1 t1/ h1 r2 t2/ ......", which store in the txt file. How to use the txt file as an input to create a RDF file? I want to use SPARQL to query this triples data.

Comment: then you have to map your own triples format to a proper RDF format like N-Triples first. So write a Python script that does this.

Comment: Following @UninformedUser, you could use [this library](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) and parse your text file to N-triples which is a simple and similar format to yours.

Comment: Thasnks so mech, I will try to use them to do this. What's more, I want to know if some tools , such as protege, can do this work?